# Longest 200 byte string - database validation max_length

Tags: python

So, working to a specification which dictates a byte length for a given variable (200 bytes) provided by end users/apps.

Using a python string, what is the maximum character length of a string, which meets 200 bytes, and therefore I can specify for my max_length setting of my database field?

(Equally I may be missing something in the byte-unicode conversion!)

Comment: Depends on encoding.  UTF-32 always use 4 bytes pr char, UTF-8 use single byte for english text, two bytes for most european languages but can go up to four for mathematical symbols, chinese/japanese/etc. so, *most likely* 200 bytes are enough to fit any 50 char long string... Unless 5-byte per char encoding exists(?) :)

Comment: Very nice explanation :) You should've considered make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on encoding. UTF-32 always use 4 bytes pr char, UTF-8 use single byte for english text, two bytes for most european languages but can go up to four for mathematical symbols, chinese/japanese/etc. so, most likely 200 bytes are enough to fit any 50 char long string... Unless 5-byte per char encoding exists(?) :)

Comment: I made JOHN's comment a community answer so the OP has something to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am missing something, but the longest (unicode) string you can get out of 200 bytes is 200 characters.

The minimum length is a different issue, though.

Depending on the encoding ('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', 'latin-1',...) you need between 1 and 4 bytes per unicode codepoint ('character', e.g. ). So while a uncode string of length 200 can be encoded in 200 bytes:

```
len(u'a'*200)== 200 == len((u'a'*200).encode('UTF-8'))
```

you can get much longer bytestrings too:

```
len(u'a'*200)== 200 < 804 len((u'a'*200).encode('UTF-32'))  # includes a byte-order-mark and 4 bytes per char
```

So depending on the encoding used, as a unicode string your 200 bytes should be at least 50 code points.

So if you want to specify the field length as a unicode string and have the database handle encoding, 200 is sufficient, in bytes it depends on the source encoding. It's possible that a bytestring in e.g. japanese encoding gets longer if decoded and re-encoded in UTF-8. I think the worst case is going from a ASCII-string in UTF-8 (one char per byte) to UTF-32 (4 bytes per char, plus byte-order-mark), resulting in 804 bytes stated above.

Comment: if the database uses Unicode normalization; it can change the length of a Unicode string